# Pgfplots asymptote handling

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the function f : [0,1] -> [0, ∞] given by:

```
f(x) = 0.5*(x^(-0.5)-1)
```

using pgfplots.

The asymptote at x = 0 is causing me some problems though.

[image: The asymptote at x = 0 is not plotted correctly.]

I've done some research and found that restricting the `domain` helps, i. e.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[no marks, domain = 0.001:1, samples = 100] expression {0.5*(x^(-0.5)-1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: Result of restricting the domain]

I'm wondering whether this is the best way to get the function to be plotted correctly.

Comment: Considering that 0^{-0.5) = 1/\sqrt(0) is undefined, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than guess how small an increment to add you can specify that y is infinite at x=0 and it omits that point (with a warning)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[no marks, domain = 0:1, samples = 100,
    y filter/.expression = {x==0 ? inf:y}] expression {0.5*(x^(-0.5)-1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```